# Intersect/merge results from several Sphinx indices

Tags: .net, full-text-search, search-engine, sphinx

Good day,

I wonder if it is possible to implement the following. For example, we have 2 indices:

1: Id, A, B, C, f1, f2.
2: Id, f3.

where: 
fn - rt_field.
A, B, C - attributes to return.
Ids in the 2nd index are a subset of ids from the 1st one.

The goal is to query both indices and get results in such form: "Id, A, B, C" (!), that will include matches from both indices but without repeats.

So, the main point is to fill up results from 2nd index with attributes A, B, C from corresponding documents with the same ids from 1st index. Can it be done on the Sphinx layer?

If no, then another question. For example, we have 2 indices:

1: Id, A, B, C, f1, f2.
2: Id, A, B, C, f3.

where: 
fn - rt_field.
A, B, C - attributes to return.
Ids in the 2nd index are a subset of ids from the 1st one.

Can we query both indices and get results in such form: "Id, A, B, C" (!), that will include matches from both indices but without repeats?

As far as I know we can query several indices and results from the last index will overwrite results with the same ids from the previous indices, but will it work if indices have different structures?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do (if you must do it this way, and if you don't have a relationship between table 1 and table 2) is that you could build a query as one merged data set of what you're looking for, then build an index from that.

In other words you could do something like this:

Given 1: Id, A, B, C, f1, f2. 2: Id, f3.

```
SELECT Id, A, B, C, f1, f2, null AS "f3"
FROM 1
UNION
SELECT Id, null AS "A", null AS "B", null AS "C", null AS "f1", null AS "f2", f3
```

Then in your sphinx conf file set your `sql_query` to that query there.

Comment: I'm talking here not about importing data to indices, but about searching through 2 indices with different schemes.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware.  This is one way you might accomplish that.  You can use this to search the one merged "imported" index, which will have the two separate indicies' data which you require.